# C#: How can I access the fields of an object from implicit operator overloading code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, implicit-conversion

I have a class that holds a bool, int and float value (plus the selected type and a name).

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class AnimXVariable {

        public string name = "variable";
        public enum VariableType { Bool, Int, Float };
        public VariableType type = VariableType.Bool;

        public bool boolVal = false;
        public int intVal = 0;
        public float floatVal = 0f;

        public AnimXVariable() {
                type = VariableType.Bool;
        }
        public AnimXVariable(VariableType newType) {
                type = newType;
        }
        public AnimXVariable(string newName, VariableType newType, bool val) {
                name = newName;
                type = newType;
                boolVal = val;
        }
        public AnimXVariable(string newName, VariableType newType, float val) {
                name = newName;
                type = newType;
                floatVal = val;
        }
        public AnimXVariable(string newName, VariableType newType, int val) {
                name = newName;
                type = newType;
                intVal = val;
        }       
        public AnimXVariable(bool newValue) {
                if(type == VariableType.Bool) boolVal = newValue;
        }
        public AnimXVariable(float newValue) {
                if(type == VariableType.Float) floatVal = newValue;
        }
        public AnimXVariable(int newValue) {
                if(type == VariableType.Int) intVal = newValue;
        }

        public static implicit operator AnimXVariable(bool val) {
                return new AnimXVariable(name, type, val); //The problem is I can't access the non-static members. If I simply return new AnimXVariable(val); it does work, but the name is gone...
        }

}
```

I'm trying to use an implicit operator to make the following work:

```
AnimXVariable b = new AnimXVariable("jump", VariableType.Bool, false);
b = true;
```

The problem is I can't access the non-static members. If I simply do 
    return new AnimXVariable(val); 
it does work, but the name is gone... Is there any way to get information about the object inside the implicit operator code to make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The problem is I can't access the non-static members.

No, you wouldn't be able to - there's no context. You're just trying to convert a `bool` value to an`AnimXVariable`. That's *all* the input data there is. You talk about "the object" - there *is* no object.

To put it another way - with your implicit operator, you *should* be able to write:

```
AnimXVariable b = true;
```

What would that mean? What would the name be?

I strongly suggest that you rethink trying to use an implicit conversion operator here at all. It sounds like you probably want an *instance* method of something like:

```
public AnimXVariable WithValue(bool newValue)
{
    return new AnimXVariable(name, type, newValue);
}
```

Comment: What I want is an easy way to change the most important value in the object. If it can't be done with all the other fields of the object still intact, I might just have to add a SetValue() method or rethink the way I'm handling this in the first place. (My goal was it to make this look like a normal field as much as possible) Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @col000r: Well *conversion* operators are never meant to change existing objects anyway - they're meant to return *new* objects. I had assumed that's what you wanted too, hence the `WithValue` method.